# Anaconda3 Python 3.6 Pillow: cannot import ImageCms

Tags: python, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I have installed Anaconda3 on OsX.
Anaconda3 natively includes the Pillow library but it failed to import module ImageCms. Here is the error I got:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageCms
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageCms.py", line 27, in <module>
from _util import deferred_error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_util'
```

I tried

```
conda update pillow
```

but got the same error.

Comment: Could you change the line in `/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageCms.py` to `from PIL._util import deferred_error`? That way the original import error will be displayed

Comment: @FlyingTeller: Sorry, I do not understand. Could you explain with more details?

Comment: @FlyingTeller: I changed that line. A new error popped out:
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageCms.py", line 23, in <module>
    from PIL import _imagingcms

ImportError: cannot import name '_imagingcms'

Answer (score -1):

The `ImageCms` module requires for the `littlecms2` library to be installed.

Download it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lcms/files/) and built and install it for your system.

Also check the [external libraries section](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/installation.html#external-libraries) of the `Pillow` docs.

Once you have the library built and installed, uninstall `Pillow` and install it again

**update**:
Since you are using Mac OsX you might want to use [this guide](http://macappstore.org/little-cms/):

> Install the App
>
> 1. Press `Command+Space` and type `Terminal` and press `enter/return` key.
> 2. Run in Terminal app:
>
>    `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" <
>      /dev/null 2> /dev/null`      and press enter/return key.
> 3. If the screen prompts you to enter a password, please enter your
>      Mac's user password to continue. When you type the password, it
>      won't be displayed on screen, but the system would accept it. So
>      just type your password and press `ENTER/RETURN` key. Then wait for
>      the command to finish.
> 4. Run:
>        `brew install little-cms`

If you don't want/cannot use that approach, do the following:

1. Download the zip archive and extract it
2. open a terminal and `cd` into the newly extracted directory
3. Run:
   `./configure`
   `make`
   `sudo make install`

That will build and install the library

Comment: I never installed or build a package from github. Could you please give me more detailed instructions, or direct me to a page where I can find such (for Mac OsX, and within the anaconda environment)? I downloaded the package, but instructions are not given for dummies :(

Comment: Updated answer with directions

Comment: installation with brew broke anaconda. What I have done so far: delete the anaconda3 folder, download and reinstall anaconda, run the ./configure+make+sudo make install. Everything went smoothly but I got the same error when running my script:
  File "/Users/planchon/Dropbox/Documents/Python_scripts/detecting-blur/mesure_nettete_image.py", line 65, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageCms

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageCms.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _util import deferred_error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_util'

Comment: Did you reinstall the pillow library after `sudo make install?`

Comment: When I ran sudo make install, nothing was done (said something like 'make already done'). For pillow, it is already installed in anaconda. when I ran 'conda uninstall pillow' it uninstalled a very large bunch of libraries, which broke anaconda down: anaconda navigator disapeared from the launchpad.